Why is $v^2= u^2-2as$ if acceleration is negative?
Why is $v^2= u^2-2as$ if acceleration is negative? Wouldn't that bring the acceleration in the answer as positive?
Suppose $v=0, \ u=90 \ \text{m/s}$, $s = 0.6 \ \text{m}$. Then, using $v^2-u^2 = -2as$ gives $a = \dfrac{-810000}{-120}$, i.e. $a=6750 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}$, but the acceleration would actually be $a = -6750 \ \mathrm{m/s^2}$. Correct me if I am wrong. (Here $v$ is final velocity, $u$ is the inital velocity, $s$ is the distance/displacement and $a$ is the acceleration.)

Please use MathJax to make your equations legible, and define the terms in your equations.

You are doubling your minus signs. Either take the negative sign into account in the formula, in which case the formula will give the absolute value of $a$, or use the standard formula with $+2as$, in which case both the sign and value is baked into $a$. Don' do both. I suggest you do the latter; otherwise we would need copies of the suvat equations for all imaginable combinations of positive and negative position, velocity, and acceleration, and the equations would not generalize nicely to more than one dimension.

It is a standard and useful convention in scientific formulas, that when you have a quantity that can be either positive or negative, its variable will be written in the formula with a plus sign. Otherwise, as your question exemplifies, this can lead to a lot of confusion. Take for example the relation between final and initial speeds under uniform acceleration:
$$ v = v_0 + at $$
We write $+at$, not because we know ahead of time that $at$ is positive, but rather because it is most natural to do it, to accomodate also for negative accelerations. If you need to solve for example the deceleration to go from $\text{10 m/s}$ to $\text{5 m/s}$ in $\text{2s}$:
$$ 5 = 10 + 2a $$
$$ a = -2.5 \text{ m/s}^2$$
As you can see there's no problem with the fact that the original formula has a $+$ sign in front of the acceleration $a$, we got a negative sign for the deceleration as we expected.
In exactly the same way, the kinematic relation in this case is:
$$v^2 = v_0^2 + 2as $$
With:

$v_0$: Initial speed
$v$: Final speed
$a$: (Uniform) acceleration
$s$: The displacement traversed

Similarly to the previous formula, $a$ and $s$ can each be either positive or negative (or zero). Therefore the product $as$ can also have any sign, and we always write it with a $+$ in front of it. You can of course always move it to the other side, where it will be with a minus in front. Just note, that's never how the standard formula is presented, for the reason I mentioned.
If anyone taught you to manipulate the signs of a standard equation like one of the above, or any other standard kinematic equations, as part of a kind of "expectation" to the sign of the result you're supposed to get, ignore any such advice. There's a good reason that such formulas are written in the way that they are, as I tried to explain, so use them as intended :)

It isn't. It is best to think of this as a vector equation: $$v^2 = u^2 + 2 \vec a \cdot \vec s$$ where $v^2=\vec v \cdot \vec v$ and $|\vec v|=v$. Written as a vector equation it is clear than you simply plug in whatever vector value you need for $\vec a$.
In the special case where $\vec a=(-a,0,0)$ then we automatically obtain$$v^2 = u^2 + 2 (-a,0,0) \cdot \vec (s_x,s_y,s_z)$$$$v^2=u^2-2a\ s_x$$ as needed without changing the formula. In other words, the formula is the one with the + sign, and a - will automatically be included when the vector has a negative sign. It comes in the vector, not in the equation itself.

The relationship $v^2=u^2 + 2as$ is a general kinematic equation with the variables $v,\, u,\, a,$ and $s$ being components of vector quantities.
Confusion often arises when some or all of the variables are treated as magnitudes of vectors.
For vertical motion one dimensional the equation could be written as                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         vector equation $\vec v \cdot \vec v = \vec u \cdot \vec u + 2\,\vec a\cdot \vec s\Rightarrow (v\hat U)\, \cdot (v\hat U) = (u\hat U) \cdot (u\hat U)+2\,(a\hat U)\cdot (s\hat U)\Rightarrow v^2=u^2 + 2as$ where $v,\, u,\, a,$ and $s$ are components in the upward direction designated by the unit vector $\hat U$.
An numerical example might help?
A ball is thrown upwards at $20\,\rm m\,s^{-1}$.  What is its velocity when its displacement is $15\,\rm m$ upwards from the position the ball was thrown.  Assume that the acceleration of free fall is $10\,\rm m\,s^{-2}$ downwards.
As written all the numerical values given are assumed to be the magnitudes of vector quantities.
What you must now do is convert them into components.
$a = - 10$ which comes from $\vec a = \underbrace{(10)}_{\rm magnitude} \,\underbrace{(-\hat U)}_{\rm direction}  = \underbrace{(-10)}_{\rm component} \,\underbrace{(\hat U)}_{\rm direction} $ and, $u=+20$ and $ s=+15$.
$v^2 = (+20)^2 + 2\,(-10)\,(15)\Rightarrow v^2 = 100\Rightarrow v=\pm 10$
With the correct result that the final velocity could be $(+10) \,(\hat U)$, ie moving upwards or $(-10) \,(\hat U)= (10) \,(-\hat U)$, ie moving downwards.

Another example, A Simple but Interesting Problem on Air Resistance, is the use of the equation $\vec{a_{res}}=-k\vec{v}$ when dealing with air resistance which is proportional to the magnitude of the velocity (speed) of an object and is in the opposite direction to the velocity.
If you read the comments you will note that the general equation of motion is unchanged irrespective as to whether the object is ascending or descending.

This is best understood in terms of energy and work.
Work is the name for the type of energy supplied when a force acts on a body which moves in the direction of the force. In such a case the work done by the force is
$$
f s
$$
where $f$ is force and $s$ is displacement in the direction of the force. Once you get that clear, the equation being asked about can be easily understood as a statement about energy:
(final energy) = (initial energy) + (supplied energy)
$$
\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = \frac{1}{2} m u^2 + fs.
$$
This is the best way to remember this equation if you really want to get a good understanding of physics.
Now bring in Newton's law, $f = m a$, and multiply the whole equation by 2:
$$
m v^2 = m u^2 + 2 m a s
$$
Therefore
$$
v^2 = u^2 + 2 a s.
$$
In this equation, $a$ is a quantity which will be positive when the object is accelerating (so then the energy grows) and negative when the object is slowing down (so then the energy falls). In the case where $a$ is negative you can if you like write
$$
a = - \alpha
$$
where $\alpha$ is the magnitude of $a$. Then you will get
$$
v^2 = u^2 - 2 \alpha s \qquad \mbox{when } a < 0
$$
but I would not recommend this final formula. It is better to stick to one formula and keep in mind that in practice $a$ might be a positive quantity such as 2 metres per second-squared (or whatever), or it might be a negative quantity such as $-2$ metres per second-squared.
(In the above I used the Greek letter alpha for the magnitude of $a$ but the more standard notation is $|a|$)
