How is the $v^2-u^2 = 2as$ modified as $v^2-u^2 = -2as$
I don't understand how, when an object is retarding, its equation of motion $v^2-u^2 = 2as$ becomes $v^2-u^2 = -2as.$

Isn’t it easer to keep the equation the same but consider $a$ to be negative for deceleration?

Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/830108/why-is-v2-u2-2as-if-acceleration-is-negative

I have faced this thing the days I began kinematics. This is how you shall address it:
In kinematics equations of motion, we use v² = u² + 2aS, which by itself cannot be modified to v²=u²–2aS. The 2md form is a special case of the first form and is used for convenience only, but this is not the exact 3rd equation of motion at all. This is a special case where net force along line of displacement is opposite to the direction of displacement.
Suppose you have to plot the velocity-displacement graph, the special case is
In appliable when the given v-t graph is v=u–gt, or s=ut – (1/2)at².
In other words, in this case all 3 equations of motion get modified as a↔–a.
Normally it's better to put a=–..., instead of –a, same for s,v,u.
We use Cartesian coordinate system to fix something as negative or positive in one-dimensional motion. Generally we take the direction of initial velocity as positive. That determines the symbol of v, s and a, based on whether their directions are same as or opposite of that of u.
You can take acceleration vector as reference instead, in case of free fall for easier solution. For example a ball may be falling down, and then a has direction downwards. Then dvertucally downwards in the positive direction making the value of u<0 (if you consider t=0 when it is already falling). If the ball is thrown diagonally upwards, we will again take the acceleration as downwards, but the initial velocity has a vertical component usinθ whose value is considered <0 (opposite to vertical downwards). For horizontal component, you will generally think that the ball was thrown towards right (+X axis)
Once again, it's best to use the original equation and put their values in negative rather than writing –a, as it can complicate the more complex problems.

I think it depends on whether the object is moving up or moving down. if the object is moving up, then the acceleration of gravity will slow down its motion. at the same time, gravity will accelerate the motion of falling.
